# error in boot.ci, boot R package

Tags: r, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

Why do I get error msg by invoking boot.ci? I would like to get the confidence interval of AUC. I also didn't much understand if d <- data[indices,] is helpful and should be there.

All comments, suggestions are welcome.

Look forward to your reply,

```
library(survivalROC)

library(boot)

data(mayo)

attach(mayo)

bs <- function(data, indices) {
# d <- data[indices,] # allows boot to select sample
surv.res = survivalROC(Stime = time, status = censor, marker =mayoscore5, predict.time = 100,span = 0.25*NROW(mayo)^(-0.20))
return(surv.res$AUC)
}
boot.res <- boot(data=mayo, statistic=bs, R=100)
boot.ci(boot.res)
1] "All values of t are equal to  0.975215095269041 \n Cannot calculate  confidence intervals"
NULL
```

Comment: You should uncomment `d <- data[indices,] ` and then you need to tell `survivalRDC` where to find the variables ie. `d$time` , `d$censor` etc

Comment: Doesn't help. So if I change the definition of bs to the following, I get the same err msg

`bs <- function(data, indices) {
    
d <- data[indices,] # allows boot to select sample
     surv.res = survivalROC(Stime = data$time, status = data$censor, marker =data$mayoscore5, predict.time = 100,span = 0.25*NROW(data)^(-0.20))
   return(surv.res$AUC)
   }`

Comment: You should nt get the same error, as its a different function. `bs <- function(data, indices) {
 d <- data[indices,] # allows boot to select sample
surv.res = survivalROC(Stime = d$time, status = d$censor, marker =d$mayoscore5, 
                       predict.time = 200,span = 0.25*NROW(d)^(-0.20))
return(surv.res$AUC)
} ; boot.res <- boot(data=mayo, statistic=bs, R=100) ; boot.ci(boot.res, type="perc") `. Note dont attach mayo - this is why your original code returned all the same values.

Comment: ah.. dont use `data$` , use `d$` . I also changed the predict.time as 100 was throwing errors

Comment: it works, thx.
is sim="ordinary" best choice? when there is no weight sampling, are ordinary and balanced the best choice?

Comment: if the comments have answered your question, please feel free to write up an answer, cheers

Comment: it depends on the model ... ordinary is sampling with replacement (non-parametric bootstrap) and a quite intuitive understanding - but it doesnt suit all models.